# Method Not Working Inside Javascript Interface Android

Tags: android

I am loading an Webview url inside my Javascript interface In Android , but they are not working;
How to To handle IT

```
@SuppressLint({ "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "NewApi" }) public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
     WebView Browser;
     String website ="http://192.168.1.4/Soft/Bigcats/Ba/";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          Browser=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1) ; 
       class MyJavaScriptInterface
       {

           @JavascriptInterface
           @SuppressWarnings("unused")
          public void Danyial(String Data)
           {
                Browser.loadUrl("http://enjoybaba.com");
             }
       }
       Browser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "api");
       Browser.loadUrl(website); 
       Browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }

}
```

Comment: Its A Bug in Android

Comment: @Dannyial what kind of a bug are you talking about?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a [carbon copy of another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457269/load-url-inside-javascript-interface-class).

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript runs in another thread, not UI so you may need to run your code on the UI thread for it to work.

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Browser.loadUrl("http://enjoybaba.com");    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have `Browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` after `Browser.loadUrl(website);`. Try to `setWebViewClient` before `loadUrl`.
2. I would do this a little bit differently. Take a look.

Declare `JsHelper`.

```
public interface JsHelper {
    public void loadNewUrl();
}
```

Javascript Interface calls `JsHelper`

```
public class JsApi {
    JsHelper mJsHelper;

    public JsApi(JsHelper jsHelper) {
        mJsHelper= mJsHelper;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void Danyial() {
        mJsHelper.loadNewUrl();
    }

}
```

`MainActivity` implements `JsInterface`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements JsHelper  {
     WebView Browser;
     String website ="http://192.168.1.4/Soft/Bigcats/Ba/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Browser=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1) ; 

        Browser.addJavascriptInterface(new JsApi (this), "api");
        Browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        Browser.loadUrl(website); 


    }

    @Override
    public void loadNewUrl(){
        Browser.loadUrl("http://enjoybaba.com");
    }

}
```